# External monitor delay lag with windows 10

Tags: windows, display, multiple-monitors

On my win 10 laptop when I plugged an external monitor I noticed there's a lag.

Like when i switch between programs (from Starcraft 2 back to desktop).

I clone the monitor so it shows the same thing as the desktop.

Can someone show me how to fix this? Or at least remove the lag on the external monitor?

Thanks

Comment: What lags? The mouse? Graphic update? Keyboard input?

Comment: That's the problem. I do not know.  There's no delay when the game is on the laptop monitor.  This i can deduce it is not the mouse or keyboard.

Comment: The screen lags.